# WPF Get Selected Row on Datagrid From Template

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, datagrid

**App.xaml**

```
<Application.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="datagridRowStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="100"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" MouseDown="row_MouseDown" Background="White">
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

**App.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class App : Application
    {
        private void row_MouseDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            /* I WANT TO KNOW WHICH ROW ON THE DATAGRID I CLICKED */
            Navegacao.Switch(new service(/* SO I CAN USE IT HERE */));
        }
    }
```

**index.xaml**

```
<Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
    <DataGrid Name="datagrid1" Margin="50,50,50,50" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyDataBinding}" RowStyle="{StaticResource datagridRowStyle}" HeadersVisibility="None" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" CanUserAddRows="False"/>
</Border>
```

**index.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class index : Page
{
    public index()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindGrid();
    }

    private void BindGrid()
    {
        DataSet bind = database.BindGrid("SELECT * FROM (projecto.encomenda INNER JOIN projecto.encom_contem ON id_enc = encom_id) INNER JOIN (SELECT codigo, tipo, descricao FROM Projecto.Produto INNER JOIN Projecto.Servico ON codigo = produto_codigo) AS T1 ON produto_codigo = codigo WHERE estado <> 'Pronto'");
        datagrid1.DataContext = bind;
    }
}
```

As you can see I created a template containing a border for each of the rows on the datagrid.
The question is, how can I know which row on the datagrid I clicked.
Is there a way to know if I clicked the first border, or the second, or the others?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**`DataGridRow`** will be the **visual parent of** the sender which will be **`Border`**. You can get that using **`VisualTreeHelper`**.

```
private void row_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow)System.Windows.Media.VisualTreeHelper
                                   .GetParent((Border)sender);
}
```

---

On a side note you can travel up the parent visual tree recursively using this helper method. In case interested in row index on which mouse is down, it can be calculated easily as well.

```
private void row_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridRow row = FindParent<DataGridRow>((Border)sender);
    DataGrid dataGrid = FindParent<DataGrid>(row);

    int rowIndex = dataGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.IndexFromContainer(row);
}

private T FindParent<T>(DependencyObject child) where T : DependencyObject
{
    var parent = System.Windows.Media.VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(child);

    if (parent is T || parent == null)
        return parent as T;
    else
        return FindParent<T>(parent);
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot. I was really stuck here. Your first answer was quite enough, i then used row.GetIndex() and it covers it (: